# Extract image from website using Selenium Webdriver (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I need to crawl several thousand subsites and extract information.

Now, unfortunately the information in question is not a regular HTML text, but a image with text rendered on it dynamically.

How can I extract these images to further process them? I'm using Selenium Webdriver on Python.

Comment: Any reasons for not using `mechanize`, `requests` or `urllib2`?

Comment: Yes, the site requires a headless browser to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very few things that you cannot do with `mechanize` plus `BeautifulSoup`.
The further processing of the images can be done with [pytesser](http://code.google.com/p/pytesser/), I however have not experience there. It would be interesting to have an advise from a knowledgeable person in Python OCR stuff.

import mechanize, BeautifulSoup

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
html = browser.open("http://www.dreamstime.com/free-photos")
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
for ii, image in enumerate(soup.findAll('img')):
    _src = image['src']
    if str(_src).startswith('http://') and str(_src).endswith('.jpg'):
        print 'Storing this image:', _src
        data = browser.open(_src).read()
        fl = 'image' + str(ii) + '.jpg'
        with open(fl, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(data)
        f.closed
```

Comment: Unfortunately, requesting the image src doesn't work - the site returns "Image can not be displayed" for every request I make. That's why I need to extract the images AFTER they've been loaded in Selenium. The OCR part is already functional (yay for pytesser!) but I need these images. The OCR doesn't work with full-page screenshots.

Comment: Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/zLT22Tz.png  I selected the address on top - I need to get that text, somehow, and full-page OCR is almost unusable.